# Usage of preg_replace() - php

Tags: php

Can anyone help me explaining the use of `preg_replace()` in following line:

```
if ( isset( $data['title'] ) ) $this->title = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['title'] );
 // $title is variable for storing title of a blog post
```

Here is full constructor code where variable properties are set:

```
public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
    if ( isset( $data['publicationDate'] ) ) $this->publicationDate = (int) $data['publicationDate'];
    if ( isset( $data['title'] ) ) $this->title = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['title'] );
    if ( isset( $data['summary'] ) ) $this->summary = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['summary'] );
    if ( isset( $data['content'] ) ) $this->content = $data['content'];
  }
```

I am unable to understand usage of `preg_replace` and it's need here. Help me in explaining this - Thanks in advance

Comment: It replaces all the symbols from the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with the empty string. See also the manual on [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

Comment: I understand that but why it's being used here ?

Comment: it looks like some king of incorrect "sanitation", ie if data came from user - this code tries to remove invalid symbols from it, constructor is not the best place to do it, better to move it where user's data are taken from $_GET/$_POST

Comment: Actually it replaces all characters NOT in the character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like whoever wrote that got a little crazy with escaping characters, which is not needed for most of those characters in the character class.  This regex could be re-written as

```
/[^.,\-_'"@?!:$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/ <-- note that only the dash needs to be escaped here
```

This basically saying that the evaluated string CAN NOT have any of the following characters:

```
.,-_'"@?!:$ a-zA-Z0-9()
```

This is because the opening carat `^` in the character class makes this a negation class.

Here the intended usage is to remove characters that are not in that list from the output by replacing with empty string.  So if you had something like

```
$this->title = 'Here is a bad symbol >';
```

This would become:

```
'Here is a bad symbol '
```

Answer (score 1):

preg_replace looks for "search pattern" and replaces found substrings with value, so `preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['title'] )` looks for some symbols and replace them with empty string

pattern /[^...]/ means - all symbols which **ARE NOT** in this list, ie this code replaces all non-alphanumeric and some punctuation with empty string, so, text like `a#b` will be just `ab`, but `a?b` will be `a?b` as ? in "allowed" symbols.

Don't be confused about many \ symbols - they are need for escaping only, so basically the list of allowed symbols is `.,-_'"@?!:$ a-zA-Z0-9()`